# Media queries in bootstrap , not letting me change size and color of nav

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am playing around with bootstrap and using some media queries to edit some of my nav bar settings when the page gets smaller. I am trying to make it so that the colour of the background around the navigation turns all pink and the text is white but for some reason this is not happening.

I am also trying to make it so that when it gets smaller bootstrap has the icon bar which you can press down and its like a drop down menu, however its way to big when it gets to mobile version and for some reason I cant make it appear smaller. That is the actual text of the navigation not the small icon

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
   .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
        background-color: #ff00ff;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 5px;
}
}
```

Again sorry if this is an easy solution but I am just starting to learn etc using bootstrap and all of this so it's all new to me. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Try to add individual classess for you (a) elements. Im new to bootstrap too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because some other styles are overriding your css.
You should use inspectors like Chrome's DevTools to see where this happens.

How about using `!important` for temporarily forcing your style?

```
    background-color: #ff00ff !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
```

Of course it's not a best practice, see: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Thanks i will try this, hopefully it helps